# The gulp plugin gulp-ruby-sass version 2.0.4 does not compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass, gulp-plugin

The gulp plugin gulp-ruby-sass doesn't work `"gulp-ruby-sass": "^2.0.4"` for the compiler at the same time it does work with its own old version `"gulp-ruby-sass": "^0.7.1"`

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    notify = require("gulp-notify"),
    bower = require('gulp-bower');
var config = {
    sassPath: './resources/sass',
    bowerDir: './bower_components'
};

gulp.task('css', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.sassPath + '/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
        loadPath: [
            './resources/sass',
        config.bowerDir + '/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets',
        config.bowerDir + '/font-awesome/scss', ]
    })
    .on("error", notify.onError(function (error) {
        return "Error: " + error.message;
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code was for old version of **gulp-ruby-sass**, new version `2.0.4` required another way for coding

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
    return sass(config.sassPath + '/style.scss', {
        precision: 6,
        stopOnError: true,
        cacheLocation: './',
        loadPath: [
            './resources/sass',
        config.bowerDir + '/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets',
        config.bowerDir + '/font-awesome/scss', ]
    })
    .on("error", notify.onError(function (error) {
        return "Error: " + error.message;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));
});
```